# requestLocationUpdates in onStartCommand cause GPS stop responding?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I'm investigating a trouble in an android software that, in the background, logging the device's location to log file. The code is like this:

```
package com.otpc.auto;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationUpdate extends Service {
    private String TAG = "LocationUpdate";
    private LocationManager loc;
    private class CustomLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            writeLocationData(location);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Update service has been started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60 * 60 * 1000, 100,
                new CustomLocationListener(), 
                Looper.myLooper());
        loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60 * 60 * 1000, 100,
                new CustomLocationListener(), 
                Looper.myLooper());
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    private void writeLocationData(Location location){
        final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        final double lon = location.getLongitude();
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream latitudeFile = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/latitude.txt");
                    latitudeFile.write(String.valueOf(latitude).getBytes());
                    latitudeFile.close();
                    FileOutputStream longitudeFile = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/longitude.txt");
                    longitudeFile.write(String.valueOf(lon).getBytes());
                    longitudeFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }
}
```

After register this as startup service, the other application can no longer use GPS service. Testing the GPS with GPS Tester applications give a result just like the device has no GPS. Only after we remove this application from the device, the GPS come back to function normally.

What's wrong with the above code. I'm no expert in Android, but from what I see, I cannot spot any anomaly in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly what the cause was, but I have experienced this problem before.  I think the problem was that the requested frequency of update was higher (or maybe lower) than the device could handle.  Try playing with the numbers in your request and see if things improve.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the `Looper.myLooper()` when registering for location callbacks:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Update service has been started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60 * 60 * 1000, 100,
            new CustomLocationListener());
    loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60 * 60 * 1000, 100,
            new CustomLocationListener());
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

If you register `Looper.myLooper()` you're registering the system Thread that called `onStartCommand()` to use its message queue to implement the callback mechanism, which is probably causing issues in the background.